# Use DetachedCriteria in JOIN Clause in Gorm/Grails

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, grails-orm, detachedcriteria

Imagine I have this native SQL query:

```
SELECT
    # .. other properties
    model.id 'Model Id', mappedCountSubQ.mapcount 'Mapped Count'
FROM
    # .. other join
    model_content_revision modelCts
    JOIN model model ON modelCts.model_id = model.id
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
             modelCts2.model_id 'modelId2', COUNT(modelCts2.id) 'mapcount'
        FROM 
             model_content_revision modelCts2
        GROUP BY 
             modelCts2.model_id
    ) AS mappedCountSubQ ON mappedCountSubQ.modelId2 = model.id
```

All I want is to extract row count from **model_content_revision** based on **model** id, with other property. So I created this query and it works in SQL editor. Now I want to convert it into GORM **createCriteria** HQL, and I found some obstacles.

I do not know how to perform **JOIN** in **FROM** clause, in GORM/HQL. I did googling and found the thing called *DetachedCriteria*, but all examples only led to use *DetachedCriteria* in **WHERE** clause.

Some suggestions in other StackOverflow questions didn't solve my problem, unfortunately.

Thanks for help & regards.

Comment: You can use createAlias() to specify a join and then use projections. 
example: createAlias('model_content_revision', 'mcr', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

Comment: I did use **createAlias()** but it didn't solve my problem somehow since I need to count related model content revision by model id.

However, I created a temporary solution by using Hibernate's SQLQuery.

Thanks for your response @JMa